# How do i fix Route table error using terraform aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, terraform, hcl

I need help with the following error on Terraform, when i ran terraform apply, everything seemed to have worked when I checked aws console but then I get the following error at the end:

```
Error: error reading Main Route Table Association (subnet-09b6d028942d15d8e): empty result
│
│   with aws_main_route_table_association.a,
│   on main.tf line 55, in resource "aws_main_route_table_association" "a":      
│   55: resource "aws_main_route_table_association" "a"{
```

The below is the code for the route table portion

```
#3. create custom route table

resource "aws_route_table" "prod-route-table" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
  }

  route {
    ipv6_cidr_block        = "::/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "Prod"
  }
}
```

This is the associate subnet with route table

```
#5. associate subnet with route table
resource "aws_main_route_table_association" "a"{
  vpc_id         = aws_subnet.subnet-1.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.prod-route-table.id
}
```

This is the subnet portion

```
#4. create a subnet 
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet-1" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"

  tags = {
    Name = "Prod-subnet"
  }
}
```

Your help will be kindly appreciated. What am i doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`egress_only_gateway_id` applies to only [aws_egress_only_internet_gateway](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/egress_only_internet_gateway), not to `aws_internet_gateway`. So you have to create `aws_egress_only_internet_gateway`.

Comment: Hey, I fixed it using your recommendation, but i got another error for associate subnet with route table as empty result. What is the issue now?

Comment: @IllJasmine If this is the case, then you have a new issue, and you should ask new question. Your current issue that you reported in this question has been answered correctly by two people.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the attribute `egress_only_gateway_id` to an internet gateway resource, while it must be using an egress internet gateway resource [1].

References:

1. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/egress_only_internet_gateway

Comment: sorry, I actually fixed that prior to uploading it, after i fixed it, i got the empty result error.